# nvidia-kernel-common-535 conflicts with nvidia-firmware-535-535.161.07 535.161.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.1

Tags: nvidia

I run Kubuntu as my desktop development system.  I have had this problem 3 times and this last time I haven't been able to resolve it.  I suddenly notice that CUDA isn't responding.  I reboot my computer and the resolution of the system is bugged out in some sort of compatibility mode.  Not knowing what to do I run through all the updates in Discover.  I reboot the system and it is fine.  This worked the past two times this happened but this last time, the system is stuck and can't install a package in the update queue called nvidia-kernel-common-535.  The error message is

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-kernel-common-535_535.161.07-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/lib/firmware/nvidia/535.161.07/gsp_ga10x.bin', which is also in package nvidia-firmware-535-535.161.07 535.161.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
```

This looks like a conflict between nvidia and nvidia both version 535.  I have tried moving the file myself but the package manager seems to be too smart for itself.

I have considered just removing all the nvidia stuff, and then installing it again, but I am concerned that the alternative opensource driver might be blacklisted and my system might not come up at all.

What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I accidentally let the graphics driver upgrade and met the same problem. I tried using the commands below.

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -i /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-kernel-common-535_535.161.07-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb

sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

It looks good so far.

```
$ nvidia-smi
Sat Mar  2 13:16:25 2024       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.161.07             Driver Version: 535.161.07   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070 Ti     On  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 34%   44C    P8              11W / 180W |    470MiB /  8192MiB |     35%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070 Ti     On  | 00000000:03:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 33%   31C    P8               5W / 180W |      6MiB /  8192MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: a good pne that ChatGPT can not do :-D

Comment: The commands worked. The desktop is right again.  Thank you. 
 Discover now has two more updates available.  nvidia-kernel-common-530  535.154.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 -> 550.54.14-0ubuntu1 12.7 KiB and nvidia-kernel-common-550  550.54.14-0ubuntu1 0 B  The first one says Update from: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (local) with More Information  Transitional package for nvidia-kernel-common-550   I think I am going to just hold off on these and wait until more people complain about issues and they get it ironed out and then in a month or two install updates again.